# VSCode suggestions don't show up after after accepting previous suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm struggling with this really annoying thing in VSCode and I don't know if its a bug or just something I accidentally turned on inside the VSCode settings.

The Problem: When writing some code, for example in HTML typing "class" it provides me suggestions. After accepting it, the Cursor stays between the autocompleted quotes (class="*here*"), but has some weird kind of marking and is not giving me any suggestions anymore. The get new ones, I first need to press `esc` and now I can type again to get suggestions.

Anyone familiar with this issue? I'd be really thankful if someone knows how to turn this off, because it's a really irritating thing.

I made a screen record and uploaded it to youtube so you can see the behaviour:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtVSWx0Qc6A

Comment: when inside a snippet you can press Ctrl+Space to get suggestions again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable this setting:

`Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions`

otherwise the active snippet prevent more suggestions.

Comment: Huuuge Thanks for your help, Mark! This solved the Issue :)